# Embed PDF and word document in excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to export data to an excel team from a table. In the table I have the file attachments (pdf and word document) for each row. I need to embed those files in the cells of the excel.
I am able to write excel with table data except the files. Please share how do I embed the files to excel in cells corresponding to each row using Apache POI and Java.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444803/read-embedded-pdf-file-in-excel-using-java

Comment: I need to write rather than reading the embedded documents.