# Insert PDF file into MSWord using Java POI API

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am using apache-poi api to create a word document.

I want to insert a PDF document into MS Word (normally we use Insert -> Object -> Create from file option in MS word to do this).

Is is possible to insert the PDF as an object into MS Word using Java ?

**Regards,
Suthershan**

Comment: Did you solve it or did you get answer of it ?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you have to use [OLE](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding). After a quick research I found no example code for WORD but I found some code for [EXCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910503/embed-files-into-excel-using-apache-poi) and an example for [PPTX](https://github.com/spilymp/pptx-tests/blob/8fb372bb58b034630f8285fa94a677569dfb5da4/poi/OleObject.java). Maybe it is helpfull to write some corresponding code for WORD.