# How to get a video object in Excel by POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have an excel file，I have inserted a video on it。How do I get this video object? I am using Java language and Poi，I do not know which APIs are used。

**Screenshot:**
[image]

I would appreciate very much if someone could tell me which APIs to use, preferably give me an example of the code，

thanks

Comment: This is ten years old but maybe it can help. [Embed files into Excel using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910503/embed-files-into-excel-using-apache-poi)