# Embed file in MS Word using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

everyone.
I am a new in apache poi.
I would like to know is there a way to embed file in ms word document (.docx) , using apache poi.

I do not have any code examples.
If anybode have code examples, please insert them.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed files into Excel using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910503/embed-files-into-excel-using-apache-poi)

Comment: Hi.
Unfortunately, the stated answer does not quite suit me, since I am looking for an example of functionality for MS Word, and in the example functionality for MS excel was developed